# Display first value (by index) of ComboBox as default in a DataGridView

Tags: c#, combobox, datagridviewcomboboxcell

In a Windows Application I have a `Combobox` in a `DataGridView`.

My question is:
How do I get the value at the first index as default?

For example, if the `ComboBox` Status has three values

- unknown  (1)
- accepted (2)
- rejected (3)

the value `unknown` is at the first index and should be selected as default in the `DataGridView` cell. The `ComboBox`'s text should be set programmatically by index, e.g. by `cbbox.selectindex = 1;`

[image]

How can the first index's text be displayed by default in the `DataGridView`?

Comment: I did a major rephrasing of the question and the title.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using WPF or WinForms?

If you're using WPF, try this:

```
DataRowView dr = (DataRowView) YourDataGrid.SelectedItem;
YourComboBox.Text = dr.Row[0].ToString();
```

Are you asking on how to get the first index value of your datagrid?

Comment: i already add value in Datagridview through Cell Define.only require index first select.

Comment: try this -> datagridview.CurrentCell.RowIndex

Answer (score 0):

In the Designer, you can set the column's `DefaultCellStyle` `NullValue`.

```
dataGridView1.Columns[3].DefaultCellStyle.NullValue = "unknown";
```

Comment: but its not index value get.it represent text not work in ndex